# How can I access global variables from outside of electron main.js in React component?

Tags: reactjs, global-variables, components, electron, global

I'm trying to access a global variable from main.js, this is where my electron app is launched.

My structure is like this...

- main.js (launches electron app.on)
- app (folder)

  - components (folder)

    - Landing.js  (I want to access a global variable from main.js here!)

Here is what I have...

main.js

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;


app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 725,
    width: 1100,
    icon: __dirname + '/app/img/sawIcon.ico',
    title: 'My App'
  });

  // CODE TO GRAB THE ARGUMENT passed in from the commandline 
  global.shareObject = {
    hlpString: process.argv[2]
  }

  console.log(global.sharedObject.hlpProp);   // prints ok

  let url = require('url').format({
    protocol: 'file',
    slashes: true,
    pathname: require('path').join(__dirname, 'index.html')
  })
  console.log(url)
  mainWindow.loadURL(url)
});

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

Landing.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import sass from '../scss/application.scss'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Header from './Header'
import Menu from './Menu'
import HelpFile from './HelpFile'



class Landing extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = { 
             helpFileName: 'Mainmenu',
             menuName: '',
         }
       }

    handleHelpChange(helpFileName) {
        this.setState( {helpFileName} );
    }

    handleMenuClick(menuName) {

        //CONSOLE LOGS that are NOT working...
        console.log(global.shareObject.hlpString);    // prints nothing undefined
        console.log(require('remote').getGlobal('shareObject').hlpString);  // can't build error w/cant find remotes
        this.setState( {menuName} );
    }

    render() {  

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Header handleMenuClick={this.handleMenuClick.bind(this)}/>
                </div>
                <br /><br />
                <div className="mainMenuDiv">
                    <Menu handleHelpChange={this.handleHelpChange.bind(this)}/>
                </div>
                <div className="mainContainerDiv">
                    <HelpFile name={this.state.helpFileName}/>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}


export default Landing;
```

I can't seem to access my global.shareObject from Landing.js no matter what type of console log I try.  Is my code wrong?  Should I be trying to export default a const from main.js and importing that into Landing.js to access the variable?   Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this issue because the React context does not have access to the 'fs' module, which is a NodeJS module, which is what Electron is built on top of.

So here's my code and the answer to your

**index.html**

```
  <script>
    var electron = require('electron');
    var serverHost = electron.remote.getGlobal('serverHost')
  </script>
```

This is my root HTML, with the markup to be passed onto App.js

**main.js**

```
global.serverHost = 'http://localhost:7000/';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PROD') {
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);
} else {
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8080/dist/');
}
```

And then, from the React component, everytime I want to access this variable, I simply do

```
console.log(window.serverHost);
> "http://localhost:7000/"
```

Sorry for the late reply, hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

In your Landing.js

```
console.log(require('electron').remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').hlpString)
```

[Source](https://electron.atom.io/docs/faq/)

But there is several mispelled names

In main.js

```
global.shareObject = {
    hlpString: process.argv[2]
}
```

d is missing `sharedObject`

console.log(global.sharedObject.hlpProp);   // prints ok
Can't print ok, hlpString is the correct name

Comment: This will not work because I can't access remote.  ERROR in module not found: ERROR can't resolve 'fs'.  For whatever reason I can't include electron or electron.remote in my Landing.js

Comment: Just to be sure, the code I posted is not your own. You `require('remote')` but the docs says `require('electron').remote`

Comment: Yes I tried yours, and it throws the same error.  I can't even import electron from 'electron' inside of Landing.js

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why, and I can't replicate. My last suspicion is the scope. You are making the 'require' within React's context; try to get it in the global scope.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do.  Is it possible to save the variable to an export from main.js ?  That way I could import the string to Landing.js?

Comment: I was referring to the require('electron').remote... That I know can not export a variable from the main.js and import it to the client side.

Comment: Do you know of anything that can?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156045/discussion-between-leonardo-buscemi-and-user3622460).

Comment: cleaned up the errors, but yeah you still can't import the module so it still doesn't work ><